# Master Boot Record Keeps Disappearing?

Tags: windows-10, boot, mbr, diskpart

Background in case it provides clues to what's wrong: It all started when I tried to clone my son's main hard drive. I hot-plugged it into my computer along with a new drive and began the copy. At some portion through copying (perhaps it was an option after completion?), my computer shut down randomly and decided to load HIS hard drive as the logical choice... I unplugged it and tried again but it could not find my drive anymore. I swapped SATA cables around to no avail. I downloaded a Windows 10 installation to an SD card and booted that in hopes to repair my installation. No beans on repair or recovery, but with it I got the command prompt and ran a few choice commands:

```
bootrec /fixboot
bootrec /fixmbr
bootrec /rebuildbcd
```

I don't particularly know what each of those do, what the differences are, or which one "fixes" my computer, but I then select the "Continue to Windows 10" option and my computer boots up just fine, but only once. The next time I power down I have to do it all over again. If I do not run those commands (or some particular one of them) prior to clicking "Continue to Windows 10", I cannot boot.

I tried using Diskpart to see if anything funky stood out. I found one inconsistency in that one drive was labeled as C which was not my C drive and my actual C drive was labeled as F or something. So I used Diskpart to swap it back in hopes that everything would magically be corrected. I ran my boot fixing commands, started up Windows for the first time, did a reboot, and still broken. What the heck is going on with my master boot record? Why can't it remain functional??

Comment: What makes you think your using MBR instead of GPT partitions?

Comment: Because GPT is a brand new term to me and I have no idea what it is :-p. Time to Googlie!

Comment: Looking in Computer Management, they all say MBR. Perhaps I did that with all my bootrec /fixmbr stuff?

Answer (score 0):

Well... Not sure what exactly fixed it, but I went into computer management and made all my partitions "inactive." Windows recovery still couldn't fix my startup so I removed all drives but my C drive and tried again with no success. I went back to command prompt through the recovery options. I then couldn't use bootrec commands. I tried to locate it on my C drive but C didn't exist. I used Diskpart to find that it had been renamed once again. I renamed it back to C. I could then find bootrec in c:\Windows\System32 but it couldn't "find the path specified" over and over. I then went back to diskpart and made my partition active and tried bootrec again. It gave me the usual "successful" spiel except this time it actually found Windows with the rebuildbcd command. Usually it never could. Selecting the one option, however, to include windows in the boot list, it still said that it couldn't do it. I rebooted and tried Startup repair again. Still no beans. I ran all the bootrec commands again and got all the same familiar "success" responses and the one errors. I rebooted without the restore media and it worked like it had before. I rebooted again and it still worked! I rebooted again and plugged my drives back in and it still worked again and again. So... not sure what part of all that fixed it since nothing seemed like it was working, but hey, it's all good now. Yay!